# adjust the tickness of wpf material design icons

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I've got this UI, that makes use of the beautiful [Material Design In XAML](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) and of its icon pack.

[image: Add user and delete image]

I would like to adjust the tickness of the drawing's line, making it thinner for small icons like the ones in this example.

```
<ListBoxItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AccountsAddOutline" />
        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0">Add user</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ListBoxItem>

<ListBoxItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="DeleteForeverOutline" />
        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0">Delete</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ListBoxItem>
```

I don't know if the library's API exposes this property, but for sure the tickness is adjustable because if you make the icon larger, the line becomes ticker too like in this example:

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AccountsAddOutline" Height="40" Width="40" />
```

The result:

[image: ticker line in icon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really adjust the thickness. The template of a `PackIcon` is implemented as a `Path` in a `ViewBox` that streches and scales it:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PackIcon}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <Viewbox FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}">
            <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                <Path Data="{Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"                                   
                      Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You could get rid of the scaling by creating a custom template without a `Viewbox`.

Comment: Can I use directly the Path without passing through the PackIcon?

Comment: @AgostinoX: The `PackIcon` defines the `Path`. But as mentioned, you could re-template the `PackIcon` element.